# Stuck application install! WHY?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I just purchased Little Inferno for $9.99 on the software center, and obviously want to download it. The first time, it gets stuck at 2.7 MB. I restart the download, and it gets stuck at 0 MB. I've tried:

- Rebooting
- Relogging
- Synaptic
- Purging software center
- `sudo apt-get install`, `sudo apt-get update/upgrade`

Yet nothing works. Naturally I am pissed off. If it's not going to let me download it then I want my money back.

Running software-center and attempting to install gives the following:

```
(software-center:10840): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: button.css:27:21: `px' is not a valid unit.

(software-center:10840): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: spinbutton.css:8:24: not a number

(software-center:10840): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: toolbar.css:83:0: Expected a valid selector
2015-03-01 03:34:49,989 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2015-03-01 03:34:50,496 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2015-03-01 03:34:50,497 - softwarecenter.plugin - INFO - activating plugin '<module 'webapps_activation' from '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc'>'
2015-03-01 03:34:50,554 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
2015-03-01 03:34:50,943 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - error creating bsddb: '(22, 'Invalid argument -- BDB0054 illegal flag combination specified to DB_ENV->open')' (corrupted?)
2015-03-01 03:34:50,944 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - ERROR - trying to repair DB failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/reviews/__init__.py", line 358, in _save_review_stats_cache_blocking
    self._dump_bsddbm_for_unity(outfile, outdir)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/reviews/__init__.py", line 377, in _dump_bsddbm_for_unity
    0600)
DBInvalidArgError: (22, 'Invalid argument -- BDB0054 illegal flag combination specified to DB_ENV->open')
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py:535: Warning: Source ID 68 was not found when attempting to remove it
  return super(MainContext, self).iteration(may_block)
No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:000] Cpu: 21.2.0, x6, 3500Mhz, 7886MB
[000:000] Computer model: Not available
[000:000] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
[000:000] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
[000:002] Using Gtk2 toolkit
No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:000] Cpu: 21.2.0, x6, 3500Mhz, 7886MB
[000:000] Computer model: Not available
[000:004] No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:005] Cpu: 21.2.0, x6, 3500Mhz, 7886MB
[000:005] Computer model: Not available
[000:005] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
[000:005] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
[000:005] Using Gtk2 toolkit
[000:011] No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:011] Cpu: 21.2.0, x6, 3500Mhz, 7886MB
[000:012] Computer model: Not available
2015-03-01 03:34:52,399 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.views.lobbyview - WARNING - skipping exhibit for: 'u'leadwerks\r\nleadwerks-indie'' not available
/usr/bin/software-center:184: Warning: Source ID 143 was not found when attempting to remove it
  Gtk.main()
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py:535: Warning: Source ID 20 was not found when attempting to remove it
  return super(MainContext, self).iteration(may_block)
2015-03-01 03:34:58,186 - softwarecenter.db.utils - INFO - software-center-agent finished with status 0
/usr/bin/software-center:184: Warning: Source ID 1085 was not found when attempting to remove it
  Gtk.main()
/usr/bin/software-center:184: Warning: Source ID 1123 was not found when attempting to remove it
  Gtk.main()
/usr/bin/software-center:184: Warning: Source ID 1083 was not found when attempting to remove it
  Gtk.main()
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/installbackend_impl/aptd.py:764: Warning: Source ID 4961 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._progress_signal)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 3583 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
```

Comment: Still no reason to use swearing.

Comment: Swearing..? I didn't use swearing. That was unhelpful.

Comment: Tone it down. And http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/damn

Comment: I don't consider it a swear word. I paid $10 and I have no way to see my money.

Comment: Try to run `software-center` from the command line to see its output during installation. `/var/log/apt/term.log` may also contain useful output of `apt-get` running in the background.